# Web3 Signature Twice as Long

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum, bcrypt, web3js

I am stuck with creating a signature using web3.
So I am trying to create a signature for trading in Sorare.com using API.

I checked the API documentation, and also went through source code of Sorare to see that the following code is used for it.

```
signature = web3.utils.soliditySha3("Some message");
```

This gave a response that looks somewhat like this:

```
0x4e8ebbefa452077428f93c9520d3edd60594ff452a29ac7d2ccc11d47f3ab95b
```

Now when I checked the signature that Sorare is actually generating, I saw that it is twice as long! Like this.

```
0x6887518887ff78b49e659d872be219b06faab171c291c81453583ddd44a54e0c205d08e4876d21ea777c0b2c932c24bec9e86881a046ecbd072041655c2d69381c
```

Any idea why the actual signature is twice as long as the signature I am able to generate? Is it some mistake in the way I am using web3?

Comment: As Sorare is a product, maybe you can ask from their customer support. Web3 is definitely correct.